# Can´t set threshold in configuration file

Tags: qt, logging

Thus far I´ve managed to create a Log4Qt configuration file and load it with PropertyConfigurator. Everything seems to work fine, I can set loggers, appenders, assign levels etc.
The only thing that doesn´t work is setting a threshold for an appender.

This is how i set up my configuration file:

```
void createNewLoggerConfigurationFile(QString fileName)
{
        QSettings settings(fileName, QSettings::IniFormat);

        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.A1", "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender");
        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.A1.file", "C:/Users/Fujitsu/Desktop/LogOutput.txt");
        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.A1.layout", "org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout");
        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.A1.layout.DateFormat", "ISO8601");

        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.ADataManager", "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender");
        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.ADataManager.file", "C:/Users/Fujitsu/Desktop/DataManagerLogOutput.txt");
        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.ADataManager.layout", "org.apache.log4j.TTCCLayout");
        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.ADataManager.layout.DateFormat", "ISO8601");
        settings.setValue("log4j.appender.ADataManager.threshold", "DEBUG");

        settings.setValue("log4j.rootLogger", "ALL, A1");
        settings.setValue("log4j.logger.DataManager", "ALL, ADataManager");
}
```

The resulting error message (from Log4Qt, I guess) reads as follows:

> 10 [] ERROR Log4Qt::Factory - Cannot convert to type 'Level' for property 'threshold' on object of class 'Log4Qt::FileAppender' (Log4Qt::Factory::CONFIGURATOR_UNKNOWN_TYPE_ERROR, 29)

Any ideas?

Comment: The code you posted seems unrelated to the error?

Comment: The code creates a .ini-file which is then used by propertyconfigurator, which gives me that error. How is that unrelated?

Comment: Based on the error message, it seems the property log4j.appender.ADataManager.threshold doesn't have the correct type. Are you sure Log4Qt is not expecting an `int` or `enum`?

Comment: I also had that idea, so I´ve tried DEBUG, debug, DEBUG_INT(the enum) and 96(the corresponding int), but nothing works.